# Git Merge Conflict (UU): How do I resolve conflict without adding file to next commit?

Tags: git, merge

How do I resolve a UU (merge conflict) without adding that file to the next commit.

For example, I just cherry picked a commit to another branch and there were merge issues. I solved the merge issue and want UU readme.txt changed to M readme.txt but it not be added to the next commit I make.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what version of git you were using back in '11, but right now I'm on 1.7.7.4.

It appears to me that doing an add to mark the conflict resolved does add the file to the stage; so my approach is:

```
git add <filename>
git reset HEAD <filename>
```

You could also create a custom git command that does this for you. I created an executable file named `git-resolve` (no extension) in a directory on my path (I like to put stuff like this in `~/.bin`) and put this in it:

```
git add $@
git reset HEAD $@
```

Then from the command line, after I've resolved my conflicts, I can do:

```
$ git resolve <filename>
```

Comment: I got `git: 'resolve' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`. I am using git 2.2.1

Comment: Read my answer again carefully. You need to add an executable script somewhere on your path named `git-resolve` for that to work (or just run the two steps manually)