# git status: what is UU and why should add/rm fix it?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-stash, git-add

Here is the current state of this feature branch.

Recent Steps:

1. Remote development branch **diverged**
2. **Fetched** remote development branch
3. **Stashed** local feature branch's diverged changes that I want to keep
4. **Rebased** feature branch from local development branch
5. Stash **Popped** feature branch changes
6. Stash **Apply** feature branch changes

Results:

```
$ git status
# On branch feature-foo-branch
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   foo/bar.php
#   modified:   foo/baz.php
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      foo/conflict.php
#
```

and status with `-s`

```
$ git status -s
UU foo/conflict.php
M  foo/bar.php
M  foo/baz/php
```

git recommends either `add` or `rm` to resolve the conflict.  What does `UU` mean and why would those be the options to fix it?

All of the information I can find about resolving conflicts similar to this say not to use `rm` which makes me wonder why git thinks it's appropriate.

I can't find anything about `UU` in the git manual pages but there is this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517124/git-merge-conflict-uu-how-do-i-resolve-conflict-without-adding-file-to-next-c) which also seems to be having trouble sorting out why `add` would work in this case.

Comment: See also the [new Git 2.31 (Q1 2021) documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766809/6309)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See `git status` manual:

In the short-format, the status of each path is shown as
XY PATH1 -> PATH2

For paths with merge conflicts, X and Y show the modification states of each side of the merge. For paths that do not have merge conflicts, X shows the status of the index, and Y shows the status of the work tree. For untracked paths, XY are ??

U = updated but unmerged

So UU means: unmerged, both modified

I think the add or rm message is a generic message for unmerged states, where the state can be like `unmerged, both deleted`, `unmerged, deleted by them` and so on, and hence the suggestion to `rm`. That is why there is `as appropriate` in the suggestion.